# Table Cell in PowerPoint not getting modified in an SWT application

Tags: java, swt, apache-poi, powerpoint, rcp

I have a requirement to read a PowerPoint presentation and modify the table in some slides for a SWT application. I am using POI 3.14 libraries. The problem is the if I modify text in any other placeholder its getting modified but the cell values are not. When I debugged I found that when I am setting the value in the cell the value is getting modified in the cell object but when I save the file, the changes in the cell is lost and I am getting the old values. The libraries that I am using is: **ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar**, **poi-3.14-20160307.jar**, **poi-ooxml-3.14-20160307.jar**, **poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar**, **xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar**

The code is like this:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(fileInputStream);
XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.getSlides().get(0);
XSLFTable table = null;
for (XSLFShape shape : summarySlide.getShapes()) {
    if (shape instanceof XSLFTable) {
        table = (XSLFTable) shape;
        break;
    }
}
for (XSLFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
    for (XSLFTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
        String cellValue = cell.getText();
        if (cellValue.equals("xyz"))
            cell.setText("abc");
    }
}
FileOutputStream fileOutPut = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );
slideShow.write(fileOutPut);
slideShow.close();
```

The code is working fine when using as a standalone java application but not in SWT.

This method is being called from the a SWT button like this:

```
okBtn.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent evt) {
          onOKPressed();
    }
} );
```

Comment: How are you using this in the SWT GUI? You haven't shown any SWT code so how can we know what you are doing?

Comment: its in a button in a dialog and this code is being called when the button is selected

Comment: Where in this code are you actually changing something in the SWT GUI?

Comment: No I am not changing anything in the UI. Its just exporting some details to ppt